# Looking for a short story where the uneducated revolt against the educated and it ends poorly for the uneducated

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story where the uneducated masses revolt and kick out the 'elites' that keep society running on a planetary colony. The protagonist works at a hydroelectric dam, power plant, or some similar type facility. Without the people that actually know how to do things around, bad consequences result.

The story is no older than the 1950s and no newer than the late 1970s.

I thought this was by Keith Laumer but I can't find it.  It's similar in philosophy to Laumer's *[The Plague](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51474)* in which the "untrainables, the unemployables" get dumped on a planet and try to grab up the fruits of that story's protagonist's labor, but the element of the power plant is not present in *The Plague*.

Other possible authors are Frederik Pohl or Poul Anderson, but I can't find it in their works either.

I read it in a single-author paperback collection (which presumably I own).

It's not *The Marching Morons* or any of those 'super intelligent elites / moronic masses' stories by Kornbluth.  The rebellious types in the story I seek are not morons, just lazy and uneducated.

Comment: This figures into _[A World Out Of Time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_World_Out_of_Time)_ (1976) by Larry Niven.

Comment: By the way, if you think "The Marching Morons" has super intelligent elites, you missed the point of the story.

Comment: @Spencer By the way, I disagree with your last comment.

Comment: @Spencer I'm with Organic Marble on this. I thought it was pretty explicit that the population was split into the vast majority of the very stupid and the tiny minority of the super-intelligent - and that super-intelligence was in fact needed to keep things going at all. Kornbluth returned to this setup a couple of times - in "The Little Black Bag" and in "Search the Sky" (co-authored with Frederik Pohl).

Comment: @OrganicMarble The elites weren't super-intelligent, merely overprivileged and narcissistic.

Comment: @user888379 There's  a subtext you're missing, informed by Kornbluth's Army service during World War II, as well as by _The Space Merchants_, which he co-wrote with Pohl. Think about what was going on then, and compare it to what happened in _The Marching Morons_.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fairly certain you're thinking of ["The Governor of Glave"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61847) (aka "Native Intelligence"), first published in [*Worlds of If*, November 1963](https://archive.org/details/1963-11_IF/page/n5/mode/2up).

On Glave, the proles have overthrown the technicians, and the infrastructure is falling apart - until Retief makes the rounds. It is one of Laumer's Retief stories. It is not a hundred percent match but it is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: That's absolutely it. Thanks! I completely forgot it was a Retief story - no aliens.